# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null keys not allowed (OpenJPA)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

- I created a DB with one table: users

  ```
  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS DB_TEST;
  CREATE database DB_TEST;
  USE DB_TEST;

  -- --------------------------------------------------------
  --
  -- Table structure for table `User`
  --

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Users`;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
  `UserID` bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `UserPassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ImageID` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `SignUpDate` date default NULL,
  `SignOutDate` date default NULL,
  `UserDescription` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `CommunityVotes` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `ImpactScore` float default NULL,
  `LinkedInURL` varchar(2083) default NULL,
  `ModifyDate` timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`UserID`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
  ```
- then I  try to add a User using Openjpa:

  ```
  private static int addUser(String pUserName, String pUserPassword, String pUserDesc) 
      throws Exception
  {
          // this is the JPA entity for the table Users
          RelationalJPAUser newUser = new RelationalJPAUser();
  newUser.setUserName(pUserName);
  newUser.setUserPassword(pUserPassword);
  newUser.setUserDescription(pUserDesc);

  usersCount++;
  newUser.setUserID(new Integer(usersCount));

  mUserTransaction.begin();
  mEm.persist(newUser);
  mEm.flush();
  mUserTransaction.commit();
  }
  ```
- I get the exception:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null keys not allowed thrown from the flush() method.

Here is the entity class:

```
    package com.ligilo.server.storage.relational.mysql;

    import ....
    @Entity
    @Table(name="users")
    @NamedQuery(name="RelationalJPAUser.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM RelationalJPAUser r")
    public class RelationalJPAUser  implements Serializable, com.ligilo.server.storage.IUser 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
private Integer userID;

private Integer communityVotes;

private BigInteger imageID;

private float impactScore;

private URL linkedInURL;

private Timestamp modifyDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date signOutDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date signUpDate;

private String userDescription;

private String userName;

private String userPassword;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to RelationalJPAAttachment
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<RelationalJPAAttachment> attachments;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to RelationalJPAComment
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<RelationalJPAComment> comments;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to RelationalJPAFollow
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user1")
private List<RelationalJPAFollow> follows1;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to RelationalJPAFollow
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user2")
private List<RelationalJPAFollow> follows2;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to RelationalJPALog
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<RelationalJPALog> logs;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to RelationalJPAPost
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<RelationalJPAPost> posts;

public RelationalJPAUser() {
}

public Integer getUserID() {
    System.out.println("getting user ID " + userID.intValue());
    return this.userID;
}

public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
    System.out.println("setting user id to " + userID.intValue());
}

public Integer getCommunityVotes() {
    return this.communityVotes;
}

public void setCommunityVotes(Integer communityVotes) {
    this.communityVotes = communityVotes;
}

public BigInteger getImageID() {
    return this.imageID;
}

public void setImageID(BigInteger imageID) {
    this.imageID = imageID;
}

public Float getImpactScore() {
    return this.impactScore;
}

public void setImpactScore(float impactScore) {
    this.impactScore = impactScore;
}

public URL getLinkedInURL() {
    return this.linkedInURL;
}

public void setLinkedInURL(URL linkedInURL) {
    this.linkedInURL = linkedInURL;
}

public Timestamp getModifyDate() {
    return this.modifyDate;
}

public void setModifyDate(Timestamp modifyDate) {
    this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
}

public Date getSignOutDate() {
    return this.signOutDate;
}

public void setSignOutDate(Date signOutDate) {
    this.signOutDate = signOutDate;
}

public Date getSignUpDate() {
    return this.signUpDate;
}

public void setSignUpDate(Date signUpDate) {
    this.signUpDate = signUpDate;
}

public String getUserDescription() {
    return this.userDescription;
}

public void setUserDescription(String userDescription) {
    this.userDescription = userDescription;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    System.out.println("setting userName to " + userName);
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return this.userPassword;
}

public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}

public List<RelationalJPAAttachment> getAttachments() {
    return this.attachments;
}

public void setAttachments(List<RelationalJPAAttachment> attachments) {
    this.attachments = attachments;
}

public RelationalJPAAttachment addAttachment(RelationalJPAAttachment attachment) {
    getAttachments().add(attachment);
    attachment.setUser(this);

    return attachment;
}

public RelationalJPAAttachment removeAttachment(RelationalJPAAttachment attachment) {
    getAttachments().remove(attachment);
    attachment.setUser(null);

    return attachment;
}

public List<RelationalJPAComment> getComments() {
    return this.comments;
}

public void setComments(List<RelationalJPAComment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public RelationalJPAComment addComment(RelationalJPAComment comment) {
    getComments().add(comment);
    comment.setUser(this);

    return comment;
}

public RelationalJPAComment removeComment(RelationalJPAComment comment) {
    getComments().remove(comment);
    comment.setUser(null);

    return comment;
}

public List<RelationalJPAFollow> getFollows1() {
    return this.follows1;
}

public void setFollows1(List<RelationalJPAFollow> follows1) {
    this.follows1 = follows1;
}

public RelationalJPAFollow addFollows1(RelationalJPAFollow follows1) {
    getFollows1().add(follows1);
    follows1.setUser1(this);

    return follows1;
}

public RelationalJPAFollow removeFollows1(RelationalJPAFollow follows1) {
    getFollows1().remove(follows1);
    follows1.setUser1(null);

    return follows1;
}

public List<RelationalJPAFollow> getFollows2() {
    return this.follows2;
}

public void setFollows2(List<RelationalJPAFollow> follows2) {
    this.follows2 = follows2;
}

public RelationalJPAFollow addFollows2(RelationalJPAFollow follows2) {
    getFollows2().add(follows2);
    follows2.setUser2(this);

    return follows2;
}

public RelationalJPAFollow removeFollows2(RelationalJPAFollow follows2) {
    getFollows2().remove(follows2);
    follows2.setUser2(null);

    return follows2;
}

public List<RelationalJPALog> getLogs() {
    return this.logs;
}

public void setLogs(List<RelationalJPALog> logs) {
    this.logs = logs;
}

public RelationalJPALog addLog(RelationalJPALog log) {
    getLogs().add(log);
    log.setUser(this);

    return log;
}

public RelationalJPALog removeLog(RelationalJPALog log) {
    getLogs().remove(log);
    log.setUser(null);

    return log;
}

public List<RelationalJPAPost> getPosts() {
    return this.posts;
}

public void setPosts(List<RelationalJPAPost> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

public RelationalJPAPost addPost(RelationalJPAPost post) {
    getPosts().add(post);
    post.setUser(this);

    return post;
}

public RelationalJPAPost removePost(RelationalJPAPost post) {
    getPosts().remove(post);
    post.setUser(null);

    return post;
}

public String toString()
{
    String postString  = ("user: " + userID );
    return postString;
  }
```

}

Here is my persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="LigiloBackendJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>                   
    <class>com.ligilo.server.storage.relational.mysql.RelationalJPAUser</class>
    <class> ...
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

no matter what I do - it just refuses to persist it with its key... any ideas????

Comment: What are `pObject` and `mEm`?

Comment: We also need to see your `RelationalJPAUser` class.

Comment: @CraigOtis mEm is an `EntityManager`. I suspect that `pObject` is the wrong thing to persist.

Comment: @chrylis That's what I was thinking - surely just creating the `RelationalJPAUser` isn't enough to save it to the database. I think the `newUser` is what he wants to persist.

Comment: right, it was just an error when copying a simple version for the site. I'm trying to persist the right object.

Comment: I added the RelationalJPAUser class. Can you take a look?

Comment: By the way, any reason why you're not just using `@GeneratedValue` for the ID?

Comment: Try changing your `userID` to `Long`, and check the output from OpenJPA startup. I'm not convinced that your columns are getting mapped properly in any case (you haven't shown column-mapping information, and you're having OpenJPA do it implicitly), and your `Integer` ID field is too small to hold the database column value.

Comment: thanks! still :-( it persists the RelationalJPAUser object with all its fields but keep the id null!!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to persist the wrong object. If you're wanting to save your new user,

```
mEm.persist(newUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the annotation `@Id` in the entity to mark a column as the primary key?

Also you may need to configure something else in your persistence.xml

Comment: yes, I used the @Id to mark the primary key.
I'll add my persistence.xml to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your persistence.xml

```
<property name="openejb.jpa.auto-scan" value="true"/>
```

It scans your jpa annotated entity classes and registers them with the jpa container.